# Count rows in an excel table where columns satisfy multiple criteria (simulating multi-filter criteria)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering if there is a simple way to count the number of rows after filtering a subset of columns by value considering multiple selections for a given column in an excel table object.

Let's say I have the following excel table:

```
A   B   C
a1  b1  c1
a2  b2  c1
a1  b2  c2
a2  b1  c2
a1  b3  c3
a3  b1  c3
```

saved in an excel table under the name: `Table1` and I would like to find all rows that the column `A` has the value `a1` or `a2` and column `B` has the value: `b1`. The result should be 2.

I am able to do it using `SUMPRODUCT` function and converting the logical value into `[0,1]` using the `--` operator:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[A]="a1"),--(Table1[B]="b1")) 
   + SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[A]="a2"),--(Table1[B]="b1"))
```

In my real example, I have more than three columns and at least one of them can satisfy multiple criteria so I am wondering if there is a way to do it with a less verbose syntax. For example, I was trying something like this, but it does not work:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[A]="a1|ab2"),--(Table1[B]="b1"))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[A]=OR("a1", "a2")), --(Table1[B]="b1"))
```

the `OR` function does not help, because it does not return an array result, and I cannot use the array formula in my real example because I would need to apply just for one column with more than one selection, but for the rest of the columns I am selecting it is just a single value.

It seems to be a good trick for representing in an excel formula a multiple filter criteria action, but the excel formula is very verbose when within a column it has to satisfy more than one condition, like in the above example.

Under my solution, it would something like this for counting rows in a Table where for each column we filter by only one value except for the first column `A` that we filter by two possible values:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[A]="a1"),--(Table1[B]="b1"), 
    --(Table1[C]="c1"), ...Table1[Z]="z1"))
  + SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[A]="a2"),--(Table1[B]="b1"), 
    --(Table1[C]="c1"), ...Table1[Z]="z1"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[A]="a1")+(Table1[A]="a2"),--(Table1[B]="b1"))
```

Since any given cell's cannot both be "a1" *and* "a2", the sum will be `1` if either is true and `0` if neither is true

Comment: I guess because we are adding to booleans the `--` operator can be removed. It could be just like this: `=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[A]="a1") + (Table1[A]="a2"),--(Table1[B]="b1"))`

Comment: Yes actually -- I'm just too used to using `--` in combination with `SUMPRODUCT`, but anything to make a formula simpler